# Firebase Passwordless Email Verification Link does not use Specified Custom Domain and Path

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I am currently using Firebase passwordless email verification for authentication to deep link from the email verification link to my iOS app. I would like the verification link to have the form `https://example.com/onboard/<otherparams>`. This would allow me to specify in the `apple-app-site-association` file that links that contain `/onboard/*` should link to my app while others should not.

Unfortunately, even when I use `https://example.com/onboard` in the "Action URL" field of the email template on the Firebase console, the verification link emailed to the user is in the form `https://example.com/?link=https://example.com/onboard?apiKey...`. I'm able to get the authentication working when I specify in the `apple-app-site-association` file that links that contain `/*` should open the app. However, this is an issue because I don't want other links to my domain (such as `https://example.com/terms`) to open my app.

What is causing Firebase to not create the verification link in the form `https://example.com/onboard/<otherparams>`?